# What is the evidence for the Noahide Laws, outside of the Talmud?

Tags: history, noachide-laws, non-rabbinic-judaism, biblical-history

This question may be "closed" but it's not "settled" if you follow the Noahide Laws as taught in Orthodox Judaism.

I haven't found any references to the Noahide Laws in non-rabbinical Jewish sources - with the *possible exception* from the [Book of Jubilees 7:20](http://www.pseudepigrapha.com/jubilees/7.htm). The few Karaites I know tell me the Noahide Laws were created by the rabbis, so I'm looking for evidence of the Noahide Laws outside of the Talmud.

As pointed out in the comments below, some research has been done looking for extra-biblical references to the Noahide Laws. The entry on the ["Comparison of Hammurabi, Hittite, and Assyrian Codes"](http://www.wikinoah.org/en/index.php/Comparison_of_Hammurabi,_Hittite,_and_Assyrian_Codes) is a book report on the introduction of Rabbi Lichtenstein's book "The Seven Laws of Noah."

What doesn't make the site is what Rabbi Lichtenstein says on page 11 in his book, before he speaks about Phillip Biberfield's research:

> That we know anything at all about the Hammurabi, Hittite or Assyrian Codes is due to the preservation of the ancient cuniform tablets and stones upon which the statutes of these codes were engraved. However, there exists no original text of the Noahide code, and never was the existence of such a text ever reported. The earliest sources to give systematic treatment to Noahide Law are talmudic, and the earliest book of the Halakha which undertakes to deliniate the Seven Laws is the Tosefta, attributed to Hiyya bar Abba, born circa 160."

So where were the Noahide Laws before Hiyya bar Abba? Neither Hiyya nor R. Lichtenstein even mention the verse in Jubilees.

The Christian scriptures briefly mentions something like the Noahide Laws:
Acts 15:28-29 (NIV)

> It seemed good to the Holy Spirit and to us not to burden you with anything beyond the following requirements: You are to abstain from food sacrificed to idols, from blood, from the meat of strangled animals and from sexual immorality. You will do well to avoid these things. Farewell.

This is the only reference I know of outside of "Judaism" that could arguably be about the Noahide Laws. Although it's barely of Judaism. The Pharisees were the dominate branch of Judaism in that day. They believed in an Oral Torah and were the predecessors of Orthodox Judaism. The early followers of Jesus who came up with these requirements for non-Jews were mainly born-Jews themselves. The fact that they didn't know what to do with Gentiles who wanted to follow this new Jewish sect without conversion in light of the Noahide Laws today is interesting.

It calls into question if the concept of "Noahides" existed then, because they simply didn't just use the Oral Torah's simple guidelines. Even if they tried to do that, they botched it up quite badly if it was in the Oral Torah since Sinai. Cynically speaking, it looks like Christianity caused an influx of Gentiles into the synagogues and the rabbis created a path for them that kept them out of Judaism proper, and gave them something to do. This explains how the Noahide Laws might have developed from the time of Jesus to when they were put into writing by the sages.

Some commenters have erroneously assumed that a mention of Christianity invokes the 'comparative religion' clause and the question should be closed. This is not the case. This question asks for corroboration that these laws for Gentiles were and are universal - as Orthodox Judaism teaches. These laws aren't just mentioned as something Noah taught his children, but were forgotten. They are supposed to be the foundation of most ancient civilizations. Orthodox Judaism also teaches that God modified them and the current version became God's path for righteous Gentiles ever since the Torah was given.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Jubilees) mentions the Book of Jubilees has some of the laws. But this is a Jewish work and it dates pretty close to the time of Jesus. -Actually, as a commenter mentioned, it dates somewhere around 100 BCE, to the Hasmoneans. It does contain a verse that describes what Noah taught his children after the flood (Jubilees 7:20). It is an apocryphal, anonymous Jewish text. Passages such as this should accompany the ancient flood myths in some form.

The Story of Creation: over 300 variations of creation "myths" among [North American Indians](https://www.gotquestions.org/Noahide-laws.html) alone.
The Great Flood: [Hundreds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_flood_myths) of variations of a flood "myth" all over the world in nearly every ancient culture.
The Seven Laws of Noah: nothing??

If the year of the [Great Flood](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/246609/jewish/The-Story-of-Noah-and-the-Ark-in-the-Bible.htm) was in the year 1656 from Creation, and the final Noahide Laws given to Noah in 1657, presumably those Laws spread from that single family by having children and teaching them.

The Exodus occurred in 2448, so that's 792 years the laws should have at propagated over the earth when there was no other Divine Code for living.

For as long as I've followed the Noahide Laws, I've been taught that 6 existed from Adam and the 7th was given to Noah. That Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob all learned these laws from Shem and Ever in-person, for years. And that these Noahide Laws were given to Moses in the Oral Torah, which he also received on Mt. Sinai.

We are in year 5784 from Creation. That's 4128 years since Noah received the 7th and final Noahide Law. The first 792 of those years that was the only God-given moral code for mankind on Earth.

What is the evidence for the Noahide Laws, outside of the Talmud? Where is the "Epic of Gilgamesh" for the Noahide Laws?

If there is no evidence, did the rabbis use their mitzvah-creating-authority (Shabbat candles, for instance) to create a non-Jewish class of Torah-observers separate from converts?